# Merge together partial duplicate data on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

i had this data set in MySQL 5.7 with 500.000 records, that contains some partial duplicate data.

| id | first_name | last_name | email | website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | NULL | jsm.com |
| 2 | J | Smith | j@jsm.com | NULL |
| 3 | Jane | Green | NULL | green.com |
| 4 | John | Smith | j@jsm.com | jsm.com |
| 5 | John | S | jsmith@gmail.com | jsm.com |

Some row has partial information about email, and some other about website and so on.
I'd like to have this result:

| id | ids | first_name | last_name | email | website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1,2,4 | John | Smith | jsmith@gmail.com | jsm.com |
| 3 |  | Jane | Green | NULL | green.com |

because i'd like to add unique constraint to email and website fields

UPDATE: in this example the "key" fields are **email** and **website**

UPDATE2:
the *master* **id** is the last as MAX(id)
for **first_name** and **last_name** is enough to pick the biggest length

Comment: What expression identifies that 2 rows are partial duplicates? For example you have 4 rows with `(first_name, last_name) = ('John', 'Smith'), ('John', 'Green'), ('Jane', 'Green'), ('Jane', 'Smith')` - what rows are duplicates?

Comment: If 2 rows identified as duplicates have different values in some column (for example, different email values) - what value do you need in its output column?

Comment: @Akina if some different email pops out (like j@jsm.com and j@jsm.com) but shared by same other value (like jsm.com) it's a matter of choice: i'd say to pick the one with greater id or longer, but it doesn't really matter which one.

Comment: I mean that your task is not defined completely. You must describe it completely. Each ambiguity mentioned above and all another which may be imagined must be described unambiguely.

Comment: What is the rule for saying that the email in ID 5 is overwriting the others from 1,2 & 4 and if S is short for Smith?

Comment: *in this example the "key" fields are email and website* Key expression which is used for duplicates identifying cannot contain NULLs.